# CSS: "Bleeding edge" design. How?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I'm looking to re-create a design like Fantastical's website (https://flexibits.com/fantastical) where the edge of a screenshots bleeds out of the page bound, and when user resizes the window, more of the screenshot is revealed. Furthermore, when the width is really narrow, the screenshot resizes down as well. Here are a few visuals to illustrate my poor description:

[image: wide]

[image: medium]

[image: resized down]

Here is the code I ended up with, hope it's helpful to others:

```
    &.accounts {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: auto;

      .text {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .image {
        width: auto;
        height: 300px;
        background-image: url('/assets/scrn-accounts.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 100px 0;
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }

    }
```

Comment: What is your question? This isn't free code writing service.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind would be to use `position: absolute` and something like `left: 70%` to push the image to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve something like the screenshots you provided, you could create a simple two-column grid and give the right column a `background-image` of your screenshot. As you size the window up/down, more or less of the screenshot will show.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
}
.text {
  padding: 40px 10px;
}
.image {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/400');
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item text">
    <h1>Content goes here</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis lectus sed risus auctor pellentesque. Proin sed purus velit. Vivamus vehicula bibendum mi euismod ornare. Proin non lacus varius lorem tempor ullamcorper at eu eros. Quisque ullamcorper dui id sodales interdum. Curabitur rhoncus, erat et sollicitudin auctor, odio nibh lacinia dui, eu tincidunt tellus turpis fringilla ipsum. Aliquam consectetur augue malesuada dolor viverra tempor. Suspendisse ornare. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll post my final code in the original question.